# I get strange characters instead of turkish characters after web scraping using lxml in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, unicode, html-parsing, lxml

I have been trying to get data from some websites using lxml lib. and Python3. But after web scraping process I get some strange characters instead of Turkish characters. Strange characters are like given below.

- TÃ¼rkiye Engelliler Spor YardÄ±m ve EÄ± (TESYEV) Genel MÃ¼dÃ¼rlÃ¼Ä¼
- Tek ders sÄ±navÄ± hakkÄ±nda duyuru
- 2019-2020 AKADEMÄ°K YILI GÄ°DEN ÃÄ°LERÄ°MÄ°ZÄ°N YAPMASI GEREKEN Ä°Å

But they should have been like given below.

- Türkiye Engelliler Spor Yardım ve Eğitim Vakfı (TESYEV) Genel Müdürlüğü
- Tek ders sınavı hakkında duyuru
- 2019-2020 AKADEMİK YILI GİDEN ÖĞRENCİLERİMİZİN YAPMASI GEREKEN İŞLEMLER

I got each sentence from different websites. I don't know how i can convert them to Turkish text.

Here is my code.

```
import cssselect
import requests
from lxml import html

def parse_html(url, selector):
    page = requests.get(url)

    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    titles = tree.cssselect(selector)

    for title in titles:
        print(title.text_content().strip())
```

Versions

- python = 3.7.4
- lxml = 4.5.2
- requests = 2.24.0
- cssselect = 1.1.0

Comment: They are most likely written in a different character encoding (than your code assumes).

Comment: Maybe they are only garbled on printing. You can verify this with the `ascii()` function: `print(ascii(title.text_content().strip()))`. If you see "T\xfcrkiye" for Türkiye, then the text is parsed ok, but broken on print. If you see "T\xc3\xbcrkiye", then the problem happens earlier (eg. some encoding headers are ignored).

Comment: When i use the `ascii()` function i see "T\xc3\xbcrkiye". So it means the problem happens earlier. How can i fix it?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with cssselect. I don't have it installed here, but if I repeat your steps and access the title with `tree.find('.//title').text`, it is correctly decoded. (I tried with http://tesyev.org/tr/anasayfa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer

```py
import cssselect
import requests
from lxml import html

def parse_html(url, selector):
    page = requests.get(url)

    content = str(page.content, 'utf-8')

    tree = html.fromstring(content)
    titles = tree.cssselect(selector)

    for title in titles:
        print(title.text_content().strip())
```

#### WHY

The unicode character “ı” (U+0131), is encoded as **0xC4B1** in UTF-8. 2 bytes.

```
> echo -e '\u0131' | xxd -u
00000000: C4B1 0A                                  ...
```

`page.content` returns a [**Binary Response Content**](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content).

**0xC4B1** becomes **0xC4** (U+00C4 'Ä') and **0xB1** (U+00B1 '±')

And **U+00FC 'ü'** (UTF-8 encoding: **0xC3BC**) becomes **0xC3** (U+00C3 'Ã') and **0xBC** (U+00BC '¼')

Comment: `b'C4B1'` only becomes `'Ä±'` if you interpret it as Latin-1. When I tested it, `lxml` correctly decoded the binary string with UTF-8 (so I suspected cssselect).

Comment: Solution works for me. Thanks for the answer scorix and for comments @lenz. I think i should learn how unicode characters and utf-8 works in detail.